# Display some columns in Vaadin grid with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, vaadin

I created Entity class:

```
package order;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "bo_order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private Long internalNumber;
    private String food;
    @Column(name="data_ins")
    private LocalDate dateOfOrder;
    private String orderNumber;

    public Order(){}

    public Order(String login)
    {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public Order(String login, Long internalNumber, String food, LocalDate dateOfOrder) {
        this.login = login;
        this.internalNumber = internalNumber;
        this.food = food;
        this.dateOfOrder = dateOfOrder;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String generateOrderNumber()
    {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", login='" + login + '\'' +
                ", internalNumber=" + internalNumber +
                ", food='" + food + '\'' +
                ", dateOfOrder=" + dateOfOrder +
                '}';
    }
}
```

added Repository to this:

```
package order;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long>{
    List<Order> findByLogin(String login);

    @Query(value="SELECT id, login FROM bo_order", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Order> findAllPurchasers();
}
```

and try to display values from @Query in Grid:

```
package purchasers;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Title;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
import order.Order;
import order.OrderRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@SpringUI(path = "/allpurchasers")
@Title("All today's purchasers")
public class AllPurchasersGUI extends UI {

    @Autowired
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    final Grid<Order> grid;


    public AllPurchasersGUI(OrderRepository pr) {
        this.orderRepository = pr;
        grid = new Grid<>(Order.class);
        grid.setSizeFull();
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        setContent(grid);
        listPurchasers();
    }

    private void listPurchasers()
    {
        grid.setItems(orderRepository.findAllPurchasers());
    }
}
```

but I got an error `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT id, login FROM bo_order]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query` and then

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name data_ins was not found in this ResultSet.
```

I know `data_ins` is not in ResultSet because I don't want it there. I can display all values in Grid from bo_order with `findAll` but I want just `id` and `login`. How can I achive this? I also tried to make `List<Object>` instead of `List<Order>` but then I got problem with displaying then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Add `grid.setColumns("id", "login")` to the end of the `listPurchasers()` method or include `data_ins` in the list of database columns in the `@Query` annotation.

When you create a `Grid` with the `Grid(Class<T> beanType)` constructor, one column will be added for every getter in the bean type. This will lead to an error unless data for all those getters are also loaded from the database.

In this case, the `@Query` annotation defines that data should only be fetched from the database for the columns `id` and `login`. The exception you get refers to the database column `data_ins`, which seems to be mapped to the `dateOfOrder` bean property, but I don't see any code that would remove the automatically added column for that property.

The easiest way of ensuring only desired columns are used by your grid is to use the `setColumns` method. That method works like `setColumnOrder`, except that it also removes any column that isn't included as a parameter.

Alternatively, you can also change your `@Query` annotation to also include the `data_ins` property from the database if you actually want that data to be shown as a column in the grid.

Comment: I think the main problem is more spring-data related as he seems to expect his repo to create instances of `Order` from only 2 columns present in the result set:: `SELECT id, login FROM bo_order`. So probably he needs to look into projections for such a subset.

Comment: Actually grid.setColumns() did a job - it shows only columns which I want even when I have all fields setted in object Order.

Answer (score 0):

Grid takes parameters from `Order` class, so if there were many getters then they were displayed in columns. I did:

```
private void listPurchasers()
{
    List<Order> allOrders = (List<Order>) orderRepository.findAll();
    grid.setItems(allOrders);
    grid.setColumnOrder("id", "login", "dateOfOrder");
    grid.removeColumn("food");
}
```

so it seems to be very easy to add/remove columns to display.